# A quotation of George Dantzig

Tags: reference-request, education, math-history, operations-research, mathematicians

In a Chinese book, it is alleged that [George Bernard Dantzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dantzig) said something along the following lines.

> It was almost impossible for someone who had never been exposed to applied problems and had only a pure mathematical background to know how to express a real world problem in mathematical terms, and it was even more difficult to solve a real world problem

Was this sentence really said by Dantzig? If so, in which book or paper does it appear?

Comment: It fits at least in the selection of Dantzig quotes:
https://www.azquotes.com/author/29405-George_Dantzig

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on hsm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following appears in an interview with Dantzig in *More Mathematical People: Contemporary Conversations* (1990), edited by Donald J. Albers, Gerald L. Alexanderson, and Constance Reid:

> It is almost impossible for someone coming from a purely mathematical background with little exposure to applications to understand how to go about formulating a real-world problem in mathematical terms.

The same interview was published in *The College Mathematics Journal*
Vol. 17, No. 4 (Sep., 1986), pp. 292-314 https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686279

Comment: Great! I find both the paper and the book. It contains other material I am interested in.  Thanks for your help.